# Getting a MethodAccessException(in event log of server) and HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized(at client side) in WCF Rest Service in IIS6.0 Win2K3 enviorn

Tags: wcf, iis-6, http-status-code-401

I wrote a WCF REST based service that uses webHttpBinding and uses JSON to post data.This service works fine in all of our internal environments. But in one of our environment which is exact replica of Production. It is not working. If I inspect in Firebug, I see "HTTP Error 401 Unauthorized" and in server I See following in the event log.

System.MethodAccessException

System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous

MethodAccessException: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(System.Web.HttpApplication, Boolean) at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)

I haven't pasted the whole event log. But,afore are the key parts of it.

I am not able to figure out what is happening, we are using custom httpmodule for authentication.

Need urgent help on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception.aspx), a MethodAccessException occurs when you try to call a private/protected method from somewhere that you aren't allowed. This is thrown during reflection, which is more than likely what WCF is doing under the covers.

My bet is that one of your service methods is marked as private or protected.

This would work in your local environment because it's under Full Trust. Your production environment is most likely running in Medium Trust. (Under Medium Trust, you aren't allowed to bypass the accessibility modifiers.)

-- Tatham

Comment: Thanks Tatham, for responding to my twitter call :). None of methods, that I am trying to call are private or protected. 

This WCF service is a REST service.So, I am using WebHttpBinding and calling the method using URITemplate passing on a JSON object.

Since, Production environment is still totally under our control(It is not shared hosting or anything). My understanding is this that we are executing the code in full trust. But, I can still check. Thank you very much for the tip though.